# Error while integrating google analytics in android application

Tags: android, google-analytics

I am trying to integrate the google analytics in my android application and I am following this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/). Now I am getting error in this step. See the below code.

```
GoogleAnalytics analytics = GoogleAnalytics.getInstance(this);
      Tracker t = (trackerId == TrackerName.APP_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(PROPERTY_ID)
          : (trackerId == TrackerName.GLOBAL_TRACKER) ? analytics.newTracker(R.xml.global_tracker)
              : analytics.newTracker(R.xml.ecommerce_tracker);
      mTrackers.put(trackerId, t);
```

Here the newtracker before the bracket is always showing error. I don't know what to do.

Kindly, Help me to fix this.

Comment: HelpFul For u http://javatechig.com/android/integrating-google-analytics-in-android-example

Comment: first update your Adt Bundal and also PlayStore Lib

Comment: @NaveenTamrakar Thanks a lot bro its working like a charm, can u tell me how to add a google tag manager please.